# javascript :Make convert array to json format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a piece of code where I have to convert my function/array into a json format can somebody help me?

I have tried JSON.stringfy(obj) I couldn't make it work, I am quite unsure how it works.

Hope you can help

thanks guys!

```js
var answer1 = "No"
var mood1 = "I'm tired";

var answer2 = "No today"
var mood2 = "Not cool at all";

var answer3 = "maybe"
var mood3 = "just tired";

var answer4 = "yes";
var mood4 = "i'm ready for it";


console.log(LearnObject(answer1, mood1));

function LearnObject(reason, mood) {
  var obj = [];
  var notValidAnswer = 'Try again';
  var shortReason = ' Please explain your feelings in more details';

  switch (answer) {
    case 'yes':
      obj.push('Nice');
      break;
    case 'no':
      obj.push('not at all');
      break;
    case 'maybe':
      obj.push('be nicer');
      break;
    default:
      obj.push(notValidAnswer);
  }
  if (validate(reason) && obj.indexOf(notValidAnswer) == -1) {
    obj.push(shortReason);
  }
  var objLength = obj.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
    obj.push("Enjoy your day");
  }
  return obj;

}

function validate(reason) {
  return reason.split('').length < 3
}
```

Comment: `var answer` and `var mood` being declared multiple times doesn't give you multiple values - you just get the last one for each. So, when you do `switch(answer)` it's always going to be `"yes"`.

Comment: There's a difference between an array `[]` and an object `{}`

Comment: "*I have tried JSON.stringfy(obj) I couldn't make it work*" what was the issue with it?

Comment: 1: there are multiple mood and answer declaration
2: Which part of code you want to convert into JSON?

Comment: @VLAZ what about now?

Comment: @Andreas , Yes I agree and I want it to become to {}

Comment: @HarshSrivastava I have edited now does that make more sense?

Comment: Shouldnt you check for reason in your switch ? since thats the param you're passing in to the function.

Comment: @NeilO can you please put the results you are expecting. How do you want the outcome of the function to look like

Comment: @Kevin.a  I want them like this for example { "Answer" : "Try again" , "Mood" : "Enjoy your day" }' - Right now they are : [ "Try again" , "Enjoy your day"] when they are printet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you tell us you want an object similar to this :

```
 '{ "Answer" : "Try again" , "Mood" : "Enjoy your day" }'
```

You cant convert your array to the object you wish, but you can create a new object and use the values in the array. Here's the code.

```js
var answer1 = "No"
var mood1 = "I'm tired";

var answer2 = "No today"
var mood2 = "Not cool at all";

var answer3 = "maybe"
var mood3 = "just tired";

var answer4 = "yes";
var mood4 = "i'm ready for it";


console.log(LearnObject(answer3, mood3));

function LearnObject(reason, mood) {
  var arr = [];
  var jsObj = {}; 
  var notValidAnswer = 'Try again';
  var shortReason = ' Please explain your feelings in more details';

  switch (reason) {
    case 'yes':
      arr.push('Nice');
      break;
    case 'no':
      arr.push('not at all');
      break;
    case 'maybe':
      arr.push('be nicer');
      break;
    default:
      arr.push(notValidAnswer);
  }
  if (validate(reason) && arr.indexOf(notValidAnswer) == -1) {
    arr.push(shortReason);
  }
  var objLength = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
    arr.push("Enjoy your day");
  }

jsObj.Answer = arr[0];
jsObj.Mood1 = arr[1]; 

if(arr[2]){
  jsObj.Mood2 = arr[2]; 
}

if(arr[3]){
  jsObj.Mood3 = arr[3]; 
}

return JSON.stringify(jsObj);

}

function validate(reason) {
  return reason.split('').length > 3
}
```

So to explain what i did. First you create an empty object called jsObj.
Now what i am doing is basically filling that object with values.

jsObj.Answer = arr[0]; means the object key named "Answer" should have the first value of the array. so in other words `{"answer" : first value of array}`

we know theres always 2. an answer and a mood. with the if statement i am checking if there is more then add more to the object.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.a! , But there is an issue if I pick answer 3 and mood3, I will miss two lines of code since it should be "be nicer","Please explain your feelings in more details", "Enjoy your day" ,"Enjoy your day"

Comment: I edited the answer, and called it mood1 mood2 mood3 , you can change this, i dont know what you wish to call them. I hope it works @NeilO

Comment: Kevin.a thank you! its not to be annoying but can you try to explain what happens from jsObj.answer 0arr [0] and down

Answer (score 0):

let [userAnswer, userfinalMood] = ["Try again", "Enjoy your day!"];
let finalObj = {
  Answer : userAnswer,
  Mood : userfinalMood
}
console.log(finalObj)

Answer (score -1):

```
var answer1 = "No";
var mood1 = "I'm tired";

var answer2 = "No today"
var mood2 = "Not cool at all";

var answer3 = "maybe"
var mood3 = "just tired";

var answer4 = "yes";
var mood4 = "i'm ready for it";


console.log(LearnObject(answer1, mood1));

let [userAnswer, userfinalMood] = LearnObject(answer1, mood1);
let finalObj = {
  uAnswer : userAnswer,
  uMood : userfinalMood
}
console.log(finalObj)

function LearnObject(reason, mood) {
  var obj = [];
  var notValidAnswer = 'Try again';
  var shortReason = ' Please explain your feelings in more details';

  switch (answer1) {
    case 'yes':
      obj.push('Nice');
      break;
    case 'no':
      obj.push('not at all');
      break;
    case 'maybe':
      obj.push('be nicer');
      break;
    default:
      obj.push(notValidAnswer);
  }
  if (validate(reason) && obj.indexOf(notValidAnswer) == -1) {
    obj.push(shortReason);
  }
  var objLength = obj.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
    obj.push("Enjoy your day");
  }
  return obj;

}

function validate(reason) {
  return reason.split('').length < 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, find JS bin link as it's not throwing any error - https://jsbin.com/yugiric/edit?js,console

Comment: @AnshulChaurasia if you see I have changed my code now where I have declared my answer and mood

Comment: @NeilO ES6 Array destructuring is the right way to achieve you requirement. Using which you can create Object easily.

Comment: JSON.stringfy will never give you an Object.